# How to trim string start from back until dash?

Tags: php, regex

i would like to know, if we can trim below string start from back until dash ?

**String**

```
doc/20-05-2013_08-44-19_Rusly_60_sample1.pdf
doc/20-05-2013_08-44-19_Rusly_60_logo.png
```

**Output**

```
sample1.pdf
logo.png
```

Comment: Will the format always be doc/{{filename}}? if so you could use explode() e.g.

$parts = explode('_', $string);
echo $parts[count($parts)];

Comment: yes always with doc.. i just want show the short file name sample1.pdf to user.

Comment: It is ok until the second part has no dash. Filenames may contain dashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
$str = "doc/20-05-2013_08-44-19_Rusly_60_sample1.pdf";
echo substr($str,strrpos($str,'_'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply explode string and get last element from array like

```
$arr = explode("_", 'doc/20-05-2013_08-44-19_Rusly_60_sample1.pdf');
   echo end($arr);
```

Comment: Does it work for `doc/20-05-2013_08-44-19_Rusly_60_nice_file.pdf`?

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it like this:

```
echo array_pop(explode('_', $string));
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?m)^.+_(.+)$/', '$1', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [strchr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)

```
$str = "doc/20-05-2013_08-44-19_Rusly_60_sample1.pdf";

echo substr(strrchr($str, "_"), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. locate the position of the dash with strrpos
2. use substr($roginal, $dashposition + 1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

strrpos looks when the last occurence of a charachter is (example it is _) When no occurence is found it returns false.
Then with substr with get the string

Then the code will be

```
$start = (strrpos('_', $string) !== false) ? strrpos($string) : 0;
$new_string = substr($string, $start);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
$value = array_pop( explode( "_", $yourVar) );
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should we calculate a position of the latest dash?
What if `doc/20-05-2013_08-44-19_Rusly_60_` prefix has constant 33 length?
May result be `samp_le1.pdf`?

```
echo substr( $str, 33 );
```

Comment: It is constant, and if Rusly_60 is constant too, than 33 is a position of the "last" dash.